The other npc character has to move, but it doesn't move at all
I'm a person who doesn't know anything.
I recently tried to develop Unity games through YouTube. But while creating, if a character gets into a collider with the Test component, the other npc character has to move, but it doesn't move at all. I did what the lecture said, but why isn't it moving properly? I've been thinking about this for months. I need your help. I'm Korean and I saw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhGSx-37fWs&list=PLUZ5gNInsv_NW8RQx8__0DxiuPZn3VDzP&index=12
Please help...
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class TestMove
{
    public string name;
    public string direction;

}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public TestMove[] move;

    private OrderManager theOrder;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        theOrder = FindObjectOfType<OrderManager>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            theOrder.PreLoadCharacter();
            for(int i = 0; i < move.Length; i++)
            {
                theOrder.Move(move[i].name, move[i].direction);
            }
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrderManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private PlayerManager thePlayer; //이벤트 도중에 키 입력 처리 방지
    private List<MovingObject> characters;
    //배열 MovingObject[]는 개수가 정해져 있기 때문에 사용하기에 적합하지 않다.
    //리스트를 사용하자. Add(), Remove(), Clear()
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>();
    }
    public void PreLoadCharacter()
    {
        characters = ToList();
    }

    public List<MovingObject> ToList()
    {
        List<MovingObject> tempList = new List<MovingObject>();
        MovingObject[] temp = FindObjectsOfType<MovingObject>();

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            tempList.Add(temp[i]);
        }
        return tempList;
    }

    public void Move(string _name, string _dir)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < characters.Count; i++)
        {
            if(name == characters[i].characterName)
            {
                characters[i].Move(_dir);
            }
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string characterName;

    public float speed;
    public int walkCount;
    protected int currentWalkCount;

    protected bool npcCanMove = true;
    private bool notCoroutine = false;
    protected Vector3 vector;

    public Queue<string> queue;
    //FIFO 선입선출 자료구조
        
    public BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    public Animator animator;

    public void Move(string _dir, int _frequency = 5)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(_dir);
        if (!notCoroutine)
        {
            notCoroutine = true;
            StartCoroutine(MoveCoroutine(_dir, _frequency));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveCoroutine(string _dir, int _frequency)
    {
        while(queue.Count != 0)
        {
            string direction = queue.Dequeue();
            npcCanMove = false;
            vector.Set(0, 0, vector.z);

            switch (direction)
            {
                case "UP":
                    vector.y = 1f;
                    break;
                case "DOWN":
                    vector.y = -1f;
                    break;
                case "RIGHT":
                    vector.x = 1f;
                    break;
                case "LEFT":
                    vector.x = -1f;
                    break;
            }
            animator.SetFloat("DirX", vector.x);
            animator.SetFloat("DirY", vector.y);
            animator.SetBool("Walking", true);

            while (currentWalkCount < walkCount)
            {
                transform.Translate(vector.x * speed, vector.y * speed, 0);
                //transform.position = vector; (There are many ways to move:(example)RigidBody)
                //이 Translate라는 함수는 현재 있는 값에서 이 수치만큼 더해 주는 겁니다.
                // This function called Translate adds this number from the current value

                currentWalkCount++;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

            }
            currentWalkCount = 0;
            if (_frequency != 5)
            {
                animator.SetBool("Walking", false);
            }
            npcCanMove = true;
        }
        animator.SetBool("Walking", false);
        notCoroutine = false;
    }
    protected bool CheckCollision()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit;

        Vector2 start = transform.position; //A지점, 캐릭터의 현재 위치 값
        Vector2 end = start + new Vector2(vector.x * speed * walkCount, vector.y * speed * walkCount);
        //B지점, 캐릭터가 이동하고자 하는 위치 값

        boxCollider.enabled = false;
        hit = Physics2D.Linecast(start, end, layerMask);
        boxCollider.enabled = true;

        if(hit.transform != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class NPCMove
{
    [Tooltip("NPCMove를 체크하면 NPC가 움직임")]
    public bool NPCmove;

    public string[] direction; //npc가 움직일 방향 설정

    [Range(1, 5)][Tooltip("1 = 천천히, 2 = 조금 천천히, " +
        "3 = 보통, 4 = 빠르게, 5 = 연속적으로")]
    public int frequency; 
    //npc가 움직일 방향으로 얼마나 빠른 속도
    //(한 칸 있다가 다음 한 칸을 움직이는 데 걸리는 시간)로 움직일 것인가

}

public class NPCManager : MovingObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public NPCMove npc;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(MoveCoroutine());
        queue = new Queue<string>();
    }

   public void SetMove()
    {

    }
    public void SetNotMove()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator MoveCoroutine()
    {
        if(npc.direction.Length != 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < npc.direction.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (npc.frequency)
                {
                    case 1:
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        break;
                }

                yield return new WaitUntil(() => npcCanMove);//람다식
                base.Move(npc.direction[i], npc.frequency);

                if(i == npc.direction.Length - 1)
                {
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


First of all, in your OrderManager.Move(string _name, string _dir) method, the 1st parameter _name is not even used. You use the Object.name instead. I still have a lot of questions to your code, but changing if (name...) on if (_name...) may solve the issue for you.
